# View Returned None instead of HttpResponse

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

i am getting the above error when i am trying to post form using ajax along with class based views
Here is the template

```
<form method="post" id="guestform">
                   {% csrf_token %}  
                    {% load i18n %}

                      <div id="div_id_username" class="form-group">
                        <div class="controls "> 
                          <input class="textinput form-control" id="id_email" maxlength="254" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" /> 
                        </div> 
                      </div> 

                      <input class='btn btn-block btn-primary nextBtn' type="submit" value="Continue As Guest" onclick="ContinueAsGuest(event)" />
               </form>
```

here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function ContinueAsGuest(event) {
            var email = $("#id_email").val();
            $.ajax({        
                type: "POST",
                data : {action : 'guest' , email : email , csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"},
                url: "{% url 'checkout' %}",
                success: function(data) {
                  $("#loading-image").hide();

                },
                error: function(response, error) {
                    alert(error);  
                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

here is the view which a class based view

```
class CheckoutView(CartOrderMixin , DetailView , FormView):
    model = Cart
    template_name = "orders/checkout_view.html"

    def get_object(self , *args , **kwargs):
        cart = self.get_cart()

        if cart == None:
            return None

        return cart 

    def get_context_data(self ,*args , **kwargs):
        context = super(CheckoutView , self).get_context_data(*args , **kwargs)
        user_can_continue = False

        user_checkout_id = self.request.session.get('user_checkout_id')

        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            user_checkout , created = UserCheckout.objects.get_or_create(email=self.request.user.email)
            user_checkout.user = self.request.user
            user_checkout.save()
            self.request.session['user_checkout_id'] = user_checkout.id
            context["client_token"] = user_checkout.get_client_token()

        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated() and user_checkout_id == None:
            context["login_form"] = AuthenticationForm()
            context["next_url"] =  self.request.build_absolute_uri()

        else:
            pass

        if user_checkout_id != None:
            user_can_continue = True
            if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
                user_checkout_2 = UserCheckout.objects.get(id=user_checkout_id)
                context["client_token"] = user_checkout_2.get_client_token()

        context["user_can_continue"] = user_can_continue
        context["form"] = GuestCheckoutForm()
        return context

    def post(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        action = request.POST.get('action')
        print action
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        print email
        user_checkout , created = UserCheckout.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
        print user_checkout
        self.request.session['user_checkout_id'] = user_checkout.id

        if created:
            user_checkout.save()

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('checkout')

    def get(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
        get_data = super(CheckoutView , self).get(request , *args , **kwargs)
        cart = self.get_object()

        if cart == None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart'))

        new_order = self.get_order()

        user_checkout_id = request.session.get('user_checkout_id')

        if user_checkout_id != None:
            user_checkout = UserCheckout.objects.get(id=user_checkout_id)

            address = self.request.session.get('address_id')

            if request.is_ajax():
                if request.GET.get('action') == 'address':
                    if new_order.address == None:
                        user_checkout_id = self.request.session.get('user_checkout_id')
                        user_checkout = UserCheckout.objects.get(id=user_checkout_id)
                        address = UserAddress.objects.filter(user = user_checkout)
                        print address
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('useraddress'))

                if request.GET.get('action') == 'order':
                    data = {}
                    data["order"] = self.get_order()
                    return render(request , "orders/new_order.html" , data)


            new_order.user = user_checkout
            new_order.save()

        return get_data
```

where i am going wrong in here? how can i solve the above error.Need help.Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your `post()` returns an `HttpResponse`:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def post(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    action = request.POST.get('action')
    print action
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    print email
    user_checkout , created = UserCheckout.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
    print user_checkout
    self.request.session['user_checkout_id'] = user_checkout.id

    if created:
            user_checkout.save()

    return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Every Django view must be a [callable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/views/#writing-views) that receives the `HttpRequest` along with optional arguments, and returns an `HttpResponse` object. CBV are not the exception, so their `get`, `post` etc. views must return a response.

Though IMHO you should inherit from `generic.FormView` - it handles much more than a success url redirection.

Comment: getting 'super' object has no attribute 'post'

Comment: You have two options: either inherit from `FormView` (the way I'd personally recommend), or make your response by hand. I'll update the answer with the last one to make your code work without breaking down in other places.

Comment: But the need to render more than one form in this view.and i guess form view accepts only one form.

Comment: Is there any other solution to render more than one form using FormVIew?

Comment: Why do i need to redirect when already i have a get_success_url ?

Comment: Sorry, I've missed you already have `get_success_url()`. I've modified the answer. There are plenty of multi-form CBV solutions (SO is really full of them). You could start with something like https://gist.github.com/elbaschid/5344084

Comment: I got out of the other error but somehow getting  'database is locked'

Comment: Oh, it seems like a completely different thing. You should gather a bit more information and create another question.

Comment: No. Unfortunately, ajax doesn't follow redirects by default. However, there is a bunch of SO answers on how to overcome that problem. Search for `ajax redirect`.